# Azure AD Web App with zombie Login Redirect Loop

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-deployment-slots

I'm working on an Azure app with a dev, a staging, and a bluegreen slot. Authentication is handled by Azure AD, and the user is redirected to the microsoftonline login page. I downloaded publish profiles for each slot yesterday and published all three. I tested them on multiple computers and browsers, and all three slots worked correctly.

This morning I tested them again, and only the dev slot works. Staging and bluegreen both redirect to the login page, but once authenticated, the dreaded infinite redirect loop takes over.

The site requires SSL, but that doesn't appear to be related to the problem. When the slots are working, getting to them via either HTTP or HTTPS both correctly redirect to HTTPS.

Reply URLs are all set as well, and don't appear to be related to the problem.

I'm not sure what to look at next. Is there an Azure process that runs periodically that could affect the slots? Why would a slot work for a few hours and then stop working?

---

The loop: (Sending request to [app]-[slot].azurewebsites.net => Waiting for [app]-[slot].azurewebsites.net => Waiting for login.microsoftonline.com => Sending request to [app]-[slot].azurewebsites.net) and so on.

Comment: Were you using the **Authentication/Authorization** or using the OpenID connect OWIN component? And would you mind sharing the URL request for looping? You can capture it using the Fiddler.

Comment: We are using OpenIdConnect.

Comment: Did you mean that after you enter the correct username and password, it  redirect to the login page again instead of to the rediect_uri you passed in the request?

Comment: And could the problem be reproduced when you using the HTTPS protocol?

Comment: When the slots are working, it doesn't matter if I prefix the url with HTTP or HTTPS. Both correctly redirect to HTTPS and the site works perfectly. Once the slot rots, entering the correct user name and password results in an endless loop regardless of protocol. I've edited my question to include the steps in the loop.

Comment: Is it helpful to open a incognito window for this issue?

Comment: No. The slot works in all scenarios until something causes it to go bad. Protocol, browser, machine, caching, incognito have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with Microsoft. When this is resolved, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @JonCrowell Did you find a solution?

Comment: Maybe. I found a potential solution and have deployed it today. I will post it as the answer if the slots remain stable for a couple days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was caused by a semi-famous bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web: Katana Bug #197. There is even a nuget package whose sole purpose is to provide a workaround until the bug is fixed. As of April 2017, the nuget package has been downloaded 96,000 times.

[image]

From the readme.md for the Kentor.OwinCookieSaver nuget package:

> "The bug makes cookies set by Owin mysteriously disappear on some
>   occasions."

The workaround is drop-dead simple. Add the nuget package Kentor.OwinCookieSaver and then add add the KentorOwinCookieSaver middleware before your cookie handling middleware.

Add this:

```
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
```

immediately before this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

If you want to read more, here are some useful links:
[Owin Cookie Saver Repo](https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver), [Katana Project Bug #197](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197%20Katana%20Project%20Bug%20#197)

Comment: Any idea if this bug has been fixed? I've got a very similar issue, seems like it might be that MS bug.

Comment: tried that kentor fix. Didn't work. Still going in loops. For some people it works sometimes, other time it doesn't and just loops - with no change in code.

Comment: Adding the Kentor.OwinCookieSaver nuget package solved this for our application.  Tried for 3+ hours playing with settings in Azure without luck.  This worked on the first deploy.

Comment: It's such a massive relief to have this work, especially when you try to troubleshoot a million things you think you might have done wrong.